# Auto layouts in xib, self.view dimensions for universal app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am developing an app which is suitable for all iPhone devices. I had taken an `xib`, its size is free from.`(with size 600*600)`, After applying auto layouts to all the subview . I still see that `xib` is rendered as `600*600`. i.e, If i run the app in `iPhone 6`, the `self.view` dimensions remain `600*600`, instead of `375 x 667`.

**EDIT**

The log `NSLog(@"View Frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));`
prints `View frame : {{0, 0}, {600, 600}}`

Actually, what i want to implement is, say we have two views, `viewA` and `viewB`, I want to toggle `viewA` and `viewB` on `self.view`, Both views have same dimensions as `self.view` frame. But the `self.view` frame remains 600*600, even for the `iPhone 6`, I checked the frame after calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`, but still same issue

Please help me.

Comment: If u want to make it free form then take scrollview as child node and add all objects in it..Then set content size for scrollview as 600*600..

Comment: i think that the main view (`self.view`) , should resize according to the dimensions of the device we run the code, but it's not getting resized. for example if we run in `iPhone 5` the `self.view.frame ` should be equal to 320*568, but it remains 600*600

Comment: At least you should explain which constraints you had set

Comment: When are you checking the `frame`? If it is before layout has occurred, then it's meaningless. Either wait to check it until a point where you know layout has occurred (`-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]`) or force layout before checking the frame (call `-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]`).

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases, It worked , I called the `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in `ViewDidLoad` and it worked, Is it the correct way ?

Comment: It would be better to avoid forcing eager layout, but sometimes you have to. What are you trying to do with the frame? That might help determine how you should proceed.

Comment: I don't know why, it's not working now, Please check the EDIT in answer, Thanks in advacnce

Answer (score 0):

I think [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] can work.

Because the Controller's View register the xib file, so self.view means xib's view, and the xib's frame decides `self.view`. Thus, `self.view` frame does not work very well.

Comment: You need to be more sure than that for this to qualify as an answer.  At the very least you should expand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this view like child view(child view controller), you need to explicitly specify the target frame after that.